# How to use QT internationalization

Tags: qt, qml

This may seem like a dumb question, but i'm having lots of trouble to have internationalization working well in QT 5.12.

There are at least 2 things i would like to do:

- The possibility to save the language that was selected by the user and the next time the user runs the app its selected (but problably that would require at least a file to save that), or run the app in the native language of the SO.
- Having a dynamic translation working, by this i mean the language to be automatically changed while the application is running.

About the first point i know that to install the translation of the native language of the system something like  `Translator.load("qt_" + QLocale::system().name(),QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath))` can be used.

The second point, i've found a solution but it requires that i place a folder with the name `translation`(on this case) on the release/debug folder where i place the individual `.qm` files.

I'm going to provide a simple example of what i've found so far:

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QFontDatabase>
#include <QFont>
#include <QtQml>
#include "trans.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTranslator Translator;
    Translator.load(":/translations/translating-qml_ru.qm");
    app.installTranslator(&Translator);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    // object of our class with "magic" property for translation
    Trans trans(&engine);
    // make this object available from QML side
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("trans", &trans);
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: 800
    minimumWidth: 500
    height: 600
    minimumHeight: 600
    visible: true
    title: "Translating QML application"

    Column {
        width: parent.width * 0.95
        spacing: 15
        padding: 15

        RowLayout {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

            Button {
                Layout.preferredWidth: 76
                Layout.preferredHeight: 53
                text:"EN"
                onClicked: {
                    onClicked: trans.selectLanguage("en");
                }
            }
            Rectangle
            {
                Layout.preferredWidth: 2
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.margins: 10
                color: "black"
            }
            Button {
                text: "RU"
                Layout.preferredWidth: 76
                Layout.preferredHeight: 53
                onClicked: {
                    onClicked: trans.selectLanguage("ru");
                }
            }
            Rectangle
            {
                Layout.preferredWidth: 2
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.margins: 10
                color: "black"
            }
            Button {
                text: "NO"
                Layout.preferredWidth: 76
                Layout.preferredHeight: 53
                onClicked: {
                    onClicked: trans.selectLanguage("no");
                }
            }
            Rectangle
            {
                Layout.preferredWidth: 2
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.margins: 10
                color: "black"
            }
            Button {
                text: "DE"
                Layout.preferredWidth: 76
                Layout.preferredHeight: 53
                onClicked: {
                    onClicked: trans.selectLanguage("de");
                }
            }
        }

        Label {
            font.pixelSize: 16
            text: qsTr("I woke up after midnight and realised - <b>IT DOES</b>!<br/>"
                       + "Everything goes according to the plan.")
        }

    }
}
```

trans.cpp

```
#include "trans.h"

Trans::Trans(QQmlEngine *engine)
{
    _translator = new QTranslator(this);
    _engine = engine;
}

void Trans::selectLanguage(QString language)
{
    QString languagesArray[] = { "en", "pt", "es", "br", "de", "dk", "fi", "fr", "it", "lt", "no", "ro", "tr", "hu" };
    QDir dir = QDir(qApp->applicationDirPath()).absolutePath();
    for(int i=0;i<languagesArray->length();i++){
        if(languagesArray[i] != language){
            _translator->load(QString("Lang-%1").arg(languagesArray[i]),QString("%1/translation").arg(dir.path()));
            qApp->removeTranslator(_translator);
        }
    }
    if (!_translator->load(
                QString("translating-qml_%1").arg(language),
                // look for the file in translations folder within working directory
                QString("%1/translations").arg(dir.path())
                )
            )
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to load translation file, falling back to English";
    }
    // it's a global thing, we can use it anywhere (after #including <QGuiApplication>)
    qApp->installTranslator(_translator);
    _engine->retranslate();

    emit languageChanged();
}
```

trans.h

```
#ifndef TRANS_H
#define TRANS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTranslator>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QDir>
#include <QQmlEngine>

class Trans : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Trans(QQmlEngine *engine);

    Q_INVOKABLE void selectLanguage(QString language);

signals:
    void languageChanged();

private:
    QTranslator *_translator;
    QQmlEngine *_engine;
};

#endif // TRANS_H
```

I want to know step by step what i have to do to have this system fully working, because the info i've found the web (including qt docs) is confuse to me.

Comment: What is the question? Did you read [this](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_do_dynamic_translation_in_QML) article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For the first point it is only necessary to save the information that identifies the language on the hard disk through QSettings. When the application is started, the QSettings should be read and, accordingly, the translation should be done and when the language is modified it should be saved.

---

- Your second point is not very clear, but I suppose you want what are the steps to use Qt Internationalization, there are several methods since some tasks can be done manually and others can be automated.

First add the following instruction to the .pro:

```
TRANSLATIONS = /path/of/some_name1.ts \
               /path/of/some_name2.ts \
               /path/of/some_name3.ts
```

In my example I use the following structure:

```
TARGET = AppTranslations

# ...

TRANSLATIONS = i18n/$${TARGET}_en.ts \
               i18n/$${TARGET}_de.ts \
               i18n/$${TARGET}_no.ts \
               i18n/$${TARGET}_ru.ts
```

Then you must open the terminal or CMD in the folder where your .pro is and execute the following command:

```
lupdate your_project.pro
```

This generates the .ts where you indicated, then you have to use Qt Linguist to edit that file doing the translations.

[image]

Then you convert the .ts to .qm with:

```
lrelease your_project.pro
```

Then you can add the .qm to a qresource embedding in the application, but in my case I prefer that it is in a folder on the side of the executable so the executable does not weigh much and could add more translations without recompiling the project, and for it to be automated the next command to be copied to the side of the executable.

```
COPY_CONFIG = $$files(i18n/*.qm, true)
copy_cmd.input = COPY_CONFIG
copy_cmd.output = i18n/${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}${QMAKE_FILE_EXT}
copy_cmd.commands = $$QMAKE_COPY_DIR ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
copy_cmd.CONFIG += no_link_no_clean
copy_cmd.variable_out = PRE_TARGETDEPS
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += copy_cmd
```

So in the end the build folder will have the following structure:

```
├── AppTranslations
├── i18n
│   ├── AppTranslations_de.qm
│   ├── AppTranslations_en.qm
│   ├── AppTranslations_no.qm
│   └── AppTranslations_ru.qm
│   ...
```

Now that you have the .qm, the logic of using it in the application is implemented. Before Qt 5.10 you had to do the trick of adding an empty string for the translation to work but the latest versions do not require it.

On the other hand in my case I implement a logic to get the .qm and so the languages available since I use a default format:

```
{Name_Of_Application}_{lang}.qm
```

The other part of the logic is similar to yours so I will not go into much detail and I will show you the code:

**translator.h**

```
#ifndef TRANSLATOR_H
#define TRANSLATOR_H

#include <QDir>
#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QTranslator>

class Translator : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList languages READ languages NOTIFY languagesChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString currentLanguage READ currentLanguage NOTIFY currentLanguageChanged)
public:
    explicit Translator(QQmlEngine *engine, QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE void selectLanguage(const QString & language);
    QStringList languages() const;
    QString currentLanguage() const;
    Q_INVOKABLE static QString languageByCode(const QString & code);
signals:
    void languageChanged();
    void languagesChanged();
    void currentLanguageChanged();
private:
    const QString extension = ".qm";
    QQmlEngine *m_engine;
    QTranslator *m_translator;
    QStringList m_languages;
    QString m_currentLanguage;
    QDir m_dir;
};

#endif // TRANSLATOR_H
```

**translator.cpp**

```
#include "translator.h"
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QSettings>

Translator::Translator(QQmlEngine *engine, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    m_engine(engine)
{
    m_translator = new QTranslator(this);
    m_dir = QDir(QGuiApplication::applicationDirPath(),
                 "*"+extension,
                 QDir::Name|QDir::IgnoreCase,
                 QDir::Files);
    m_dir.cd("i18n");
    m_languages.clear();
    for(QString entry: m_dir.entryList()){
        entry.remove(0, QGuiApplication::applicationName().length()+1);
        entry.chop(extension.length());
        m_languages.append(entry);
    }
    emit languagesChanged();
    QSettings settings;
    QString lang =settings.value("Language/current", QLocale::system().bcp47Name()).toString();
    selectLanguage(lang);
}

QStringList Translator::languages() const
{
    return m_languages;
}

QString Translator::currentLanguage() const
{
    return m_currentLanguage;
}

QString Translator::languageByCode(const QString &code)
{
    QLocale lo(code);
    return QLocale::languageToString(lo.language());
}

void Translator::selectLanguage(const QString &language)
{
    qApp->removeTranslator(m_translator);
    if(m_languages.contains(language)){
        QString file = QString("%1_%2%3").arg(QGuiApplication::applicationName()).arg(language).arg(extension);
        if(m_translator->load(m_dir.absoluteFilePath(file))){
           m_currentLanguage = language;
           QSettings settings;
           settings.setValue("Language/current", language);
           emit currentLanguageChanged();
        }
    }
    qApp->installTranslator(m_translator);
    m_engine->retranslate();
    emit languageChanged();
}
```

And then it applies to your project:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "translator.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("Translations INC");
    QCoreApplication::setOrganizationDomain("translations.com");

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    Translator trans(&engine);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("trans", &trans);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: 800
    minimumWidth: 500
    height: 600
    minimumHeight: 600
    visible: true
    title: "Translating QML application"

    Column {
        width: parent.width * 0.95
        spacing: 15
        padding: 15
        RowLayout {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            Repeater{
                model: trans.languages
                Button{
                    id: btn
                    property string code: modelData
                    text: trans.languageByCode(code)
                    onClicked: trans.selectLanguage(btn.code)
                    Layout.preferredWidth: 100
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 50
                    highlighted: code == trans.currentLanguage
                }
            }
        }
        Label {
            font.pixelSize: 16
            text: qsTr("I woke up after midnight and realised - <b>IT DOES</b>!<br/>"
                       + "Everything goes according to the plan.")
        }
    }
}
```

The complete example you find [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/53673924).

Comment: thanks a lot by your answer @eyllanesc i will check it. By dynamic translation i mean for the language to be changed on the application on runtime.

Comment: The code you have to create a folder with trans on side with the .exe is giving me error ```Cannot create directory``` ```aborting```. You put it on .pro file right?

Comment: I don't know if this matters but i'm on a win platform.

Comment: @Nmaster88 You have to execute the command lupdate by opening a cmd that is located in the same .pro folder. If you have problems, I could help you through teamviewer

Comment: Ok, but still that lines gave error. For now ill use the embedded translation (in the executable) but on future ill try that again. Ill check the QSettings. Thanks